# Visual cron GUI

Tags: gratis, linux, ubuntu, gui, scheduling

Specifically, I am looking for a GUI-based crontab editor for Ubuntu 12.04 (I know, I know, but the company insists that we use a 12.04 VM for development, and if we upgrade it, our tools break).

Preferably Gnome, as I don't want to drag in too many KDE dependencies, but I don't rule it out.

Gratis, of course (which leads me to wonder if this something similar for Windows, other than [this](http://www.visualcron.com/) - which costs a whopping $349 !!).

Don't get wrong; a Windows app would be a nice bonus, and should interest others here, but my question is specific to Ubuntu, v12.04.

Comment: For Windows, I am very impressed by the free http://www.automationworkshop.org/overview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at [Gnome Scheduler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule/) (Yes, it's Gnome and run's on Ubuntu and it's free)

> GNOME GUI for configuring a users' cron (automatic jobs).
>
> Some of its features are:
>
> - Templates support so that you won't have to create the same task again and again.
> - If run as root, you can edit any user's crontab and "at" tasks.
> - Human-readable strings like "Every hour" instead of "0 * * * *".
> - Advanced mode for crontab experts.
> - A calendar allows you to choose the day you want a task executed.
>
> [image]

Comment: Not available for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: -1 link is broken. Please provide install instructions (I'm on Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: @Jonathan Then find the link on Google and edit it lol

Answer (score 3):

<sup>**Edit:** two hours after posting my answer, [ComFreek](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/583/comfreek) detected it is the same product as in [Tom's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/21565/185) where it was named slightly different, and I didn't recognize it by the screenshot. For the additional details and screenshots, I leave my answer here nevertheless.</sup>

I don't use a GUI for Cron, but for beginners, **[Gnome-Schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/)** looks great and fitting all your requirements:

- **Preferably Gnome:** Yupp, that's already in the name
- **Gratis:** Yes.
- **GUI based crontab editor:** Yes.
- **Ubuntu:** Yes, that's what the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GNOME_Schedule) (German) says :) It's in "universe".

You can find a closer description in an [article on UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/schedule-tasks-using-gnome-schedule-a-cron-at-gui-in-ubuntu.html), which also includes some screenshots. Let me pick two:

[image: Create a task (basic)] [image: Create a task (advanced)]
<sup>Create a new task in *Gnome Schedule* (source: [UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/schedule-tasks-using-gnome-schedule-a-cron-at-gui-in-ubuntu.html); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Another nice quick tutorial can be found [at Dambalah](http://dambalah.com/2009/06/04/using-cron-to-treat-my-strained-muscle/), and its screenshots a.o. show how a list of existing jobs is presented:

[image: List of scheduled jobs]
<sup>List of scheduled jobs (source: [Dambalah](http://dambalah.com/2009/06/04/using-cron-to-treat-my-strained-muscle/))</sup>

[An article by Bart Bania](https://blog.bartbania.com/linux-2/cron-jobs-with-gui/) shows another interesting screenshot:

[image: new task (detailed)]
<sup>New Job Details (source: [Bart Bania](https://blog.bartbania.com/linux-2/cron-jobs-with-gui/))</sup>

**Conclusion:** When in need for a Cron GUI on Gnome, *Gnome Schedule* should fit your every needs. The menu bar shows I didn't even cover all features here (e.g. templates) – but as I covered all you've been after, that's for you to find out. Enjoy!

Comment: Is this the same software which Tom suggested in the [other answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/21565/583)? Maybe that should be stated to avoid confusion or edited into one answer only. In any case, I'd keep the additional screeshots, though.

Comment: @ComFreek looks like you're correct: in Tom's answer the software was named slightly different (and the screenshot didn't look familiar to me) – but the link there seems to point to the same software. Sorry for that – as you suggested, I will update my answer to point that out (edit: done, with credits to you for your find). Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Not available for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @SDsolar and vice-versa: at the time the answer was written, 15.04 / 14.04 LTS were the latest Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Is there a PPA or snap for this? I'm on 19.04

Comment: @Jonathan I don't know, I'm not using it myself. Maybe someone else can tell.

Answer (score 1):

**Gnome Scheduler** can easily be installed in Linux Mint 18.3 and looks, at first sight, working very well.

Just download and manually install:

- `python-support` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/python-support/download (two more packages required which are installed automatically)
- `gnome-schedule` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/gnome-schedule/download

That's all!

[image]

Comment: After some time of testing, it looks working **without problem at all**!

Comment: Link broken: `Error two or more packages specified (gnome-schedule trusty)`

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry, but I do not have the knowledge to help you. FYI, the program still runs wo problem, after many updates being done.